# TFS Corrupted Database Project Odyssee

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

1. I have been upgrading to another Visual Studio Version 2013 (Update 3) on another machine dev machine.
2. I then tried to create a test project in an existing collection. it crashed. Tried it three times then deleted the corrupted projects.
3. After that I tought. Well I should upgrade to TFS 2013 (Update 3) too. So it tried to Upgrade my existing collections. It failed for the collection with the corrupted project.
4. So I tought its easy just restore the database. But thats not so easy. And it tells me that I need to restore the configuration db too. In order to do so it says I need to rename the configuration db. But then I cannot start the management tool to restore ?! It freezes.
5. What would you suggest? I have a backup but I cannot restore it so far. And I do not understand why it tells me that I need to restore the configuration backup too. I always tought that collections are independent.

Here are some addition screenshots:

Upgrade progess problem:
[image: TFS Upgrade Progess problem]
Complete Screenshot:
[image]

```
[2014-08-07 23:30:13Z][Error] TF400744: An error occurred while executing the following script: SetRecoveryModelToSimple.sql. Failed batch starts on the line 1. Statement line: 1. Script line: 1. Error: 5069 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
```

As suggested I have run the best practice analyzer. 
[image]

The upgrade log is actually large. I am posting just the last lines:

```
"[Info   @23:29:51.189] 
[Info   @23:29:51.189] +-+-+-+-+-| ResultsSqmData |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @23:29:51.189] Feature: ApplicationTier (1)
[Info   @23:29:51.190] Feature: ApplicationTier; previousFailure: False
[Info   @23:29:51.192] Error count: 0
[Info   @23:29:51.192] Warning count: 0
[Info   @23:29:51.192] Overall Result: TotalSuccess (1)
[Info   @23:29:51.192] WebSiteData: 9
[Info   @23:29:51.192] SqlData: 8
[Info   @23:29:51.193] RSData: 0
[Info   @23:29:51.193] WSSData: 0
[Info   @23:29:51.193] Wizard: UpgradeWizard (4)
[Info   @23:29:51.193] TfsConfigData: 8194
[Info   @23:29:51.197] serviceLevel: Dev12.M68
[Info   @23:29:51.197] Fatal Error Location: 0
[Info   @23:29:51.197] Activity = ApplicationTierUpgrade (4)
[Info   @23:29:53.053] ResultSqmData.UpdateIssues
[Info   @23:29:53.068] no issues
[Error  @06:53:08.370] TF400744: An error occurred while executing the following script: SetRecoveryModelToSimple.sql. Failed batch starts on the line 1. Statement line: 1. Script line: 1. Error: 5069 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
[Info   @06:53:08.385] To configure the new features for a team project, follow the steps in http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=229859 
"
```

[image: Start error]

When I try to detatch it this occurs:

```
TF401219: The team project collection 'XXX' cannot be detached because its version ID is different than the ID for the configuration database. The collection has the following version: Dev12.M62. The Team Foundation Server is at the following version: Dev12.M68.
```

When I try to restore a backup this occurs:

```
TF400990: Database Tfs_Configuration exists on SQL instance NUBO-XXX\SqlExpress. Please drop or rename the existing database before the restore operation
```

Comment: I suggest you find the whitepapers and documentation describing everything that can go wrong during a TFS upgrade. TFS is an enterprise system, it needs enterprise attention.

Comment: Can you run the Best Practice Analyzer for TFS on post the results? http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: What exactly is your advice. As far as I get. You say: I should read the manual. And please tell us what you want to says with "enterprise attention".

Comment: @Wouter de Kort: I will do this thank you for this constructive comment.

Comment: I cannot understand why people vote for close here. Please tell me.

Comment: The BPA is not mentioning anything on a corrupt collection or projects that have not been fully deleted? Can you show us the full configuration log that the wizard mentions?

Comment: I found a 70+ page document describing everything that could go wrong during a TFS upgrade, but unfortunately I can't find the link right now, sorry. And by enterprise attention I mean that you need people that have very good knowledge of TFS since it's so large and complex.

Comment: As I "just" want to use the version control part I think it should be managable for a small team too. I learned to install and maintain SVN in earlier days. In case you would need two developer and two  other people learning and maintaining TFS something would be really wrong about TFS (at least for what we would need it). But please thats all off topic. I need serious advice.

Comment: If you want TFS for a small team checkout MSFT's hosted TFS called Visual Studio Online.  It's free for teams up to 5 and you'll have a full team of engineers monitoring and upgrading the service.   Your question is off topic here because it doesn't involve a development question.  It's a SysAdmin question which is for ServerFault.

Comment: Can the question be moved to Server fault?

Comment: Update: I moved to Visual Studio online and I am happy with it, I will never try again to host a TFS on our side.

Answer (score 0):

First of all keep calm.

I would try to complete the upgrade before trying other options. From what you show seems you have issue at SQL level, could be a permission: check both the TFS service account and the your user.

If you want to rollback, and you used the integrated backup, you have to restore all databases in practice.